# CDI injection in JAX-RS on JBoss EAP 6

Tags: java, dependency-injection, cdi, jboss-eap-6

I've got a JAX-RS class:

```
@Path("/")
@RequestScoped
public class Customer {
    @Inject
    private CustomerDAO cDao;
}
```

Where CustomerDAO is a POJO and I've got an empty beans.xml in WEB-INF.

ciao remains null. I've tried scattering @ManagedBean, @Stateless, @Named, etc. around and nothing seems to make much difference. Any suggestions? How can you even debug this?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your `Customer` Rest Resource is not in the same jar with the `beans.xml` file. After packaging, unzip the jar file to check that.

Answer (score 0):

I had an Application class that looked something like this:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private Set<Object> resourceObjects = new HashSet<Object>();

    public MyApplication() {
        resourceObjects.add(new Customer());
    }
    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        return resourceObjects;
    }
}
```

It turns out that (i) I didn't need to put anything in the body of this class for it to still work and that (ii) by calling new I was skipping CDI. Not overriding getSingletons fixes the behaviour.